# How to install a screen door?

Tags: doors, installation

I have been thinking of adding a screen door to an existing sliding glass door on my balcony.

I measured my door frame and purchased a screen door, now I am not sure how to install it.

Can I install the door without removing the glass door from its place? 
I fear that once I remove it from the track I will not be able to put it back.

Comment: Will this be a sliding screen door in a track inside of the track for the glass door? I cannot see why you would need to remove the glass doors. It takes a certain combination of strength and arm length for one  person to remove glass doors and reinstall them.

Comment: Exactly what Jim said. Is it possible for you to add a few pictures of your situation?

Answer (score 1):

The sliding screen door is completely independent of the the sliding glass door. There is no need to remove the glass door to install a screen door. If you are not experienced at removing sliding glass doors and you try to do so, even with a helper, you risk damaging the door and personal injury.

The light sliding screen doors I am familiar with have two spring loaded rollers on the bottom (possibly on the top too). Insert the top of the door into the top slot and position the bottom as close to the bottom track as you can. Use a flat metal blade (e.g. a putty knife) to lift up one roller, push the door over the track and release the roller. Repeat on the other roller.